# Varying definitions for concavity of a function

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I've been working on concavity of functions and have noticed that different texts define this notion in different ways.

Specifically, some texts include the endpoints of an interval when describing concavity and others choose to exclude the endpoints. Why is this the case? Are there benefits of one approach over the other? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual definition is like this:

A real-valued function $f$ defined on a set $D$ is concave ("concave down" in the language of many calculus textbooks) if for all
$x$ and  $y $ in $D$ and $0 \le t \le 1$, $$f(tx + (1-t) y) \ge t f(x) + (1-t) f(y)$$
It is convex ("concave up") if for all $x$ and  $y$ in $D$ and $0 \le t \le 1$,
$$f(tx + (1-t) y) \le t f(x) + (1-t) f(y)$$

For this to make sense, the domain $D$ must be a convex set, i.e. for all
$x$ and $y$ in $D$ and $0 \le t \le 1$, $t x + (1-t) y$ is in  $D$.  In the one-variable case, that makes it an interval.
It may be open or closed or neither.

Some authors may choose to
 only consider concave functions defined on open intervals, some may prefer closed intervals.  It doesn't matter much.  A more serious problem is that many calculus texts only consider the cases where the functions are differentiable, or even twice differentiable.

Comment: For concavity to be defined the function should be twice differentiable, shouldn't it ?

Comment: No, it does not need to be differentiable even once.  For example, $-|x|$ is concave.